# Is it possible to run a Perl Script on MS Surface?

Tags: c#, perl, pixelsense

And if this is possible, how can I do that?

Comment: @Hamish How is that relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NEW VERSION OF ANSWER BASED ON CLARIFICATION:

http://strawberryperl.com/

or

http://www.activestate.com/activeperl

Comment: It is Windows Vista running, but is there an Perl Intepreter (or how do you call this?) available?

Comment: Thanks! Now I have just to see how to install something on the MS Surface ;)

Comment: Hook up a USB keyboard and press <ctrl><shift><esc> I would think ;) ... I have no clue. But since it's Vista at it's core, this will work.

Answer (score 2):

Surface v1 sp1 usese Windows Vista under the hood, so any Perl functionality that you get on Windows Vista, you get with Microsoft Surface.